# Como corrigir: TypeError: 'float' object is not callable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos, funções, método

fiz uma programa básico com orientação a objetos em Python, mas quando tento rodar aparece: TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

```
class Aluno:
 def __init__(self,nome,nota_1,nota_2):
    self.nome  = nome
    self.nota_1= nota_1
    self.nota_2= nota_2
    self.media= 0.0

 def media(self):
     self.media = (self.nota_1+self.nota_2)/2.0
     return self.media

 def imprimir(self):
     print(f"{self.nome}, você tirou {self.nota_1} na primeira nota e {self.nota_2} na sua segunda nota, sua média ficou {self.media}.")

 def resultado(self):
     if self.media>=6.0:
         print("Você foi aprovado")
     else:
         print("Você foi reprovado")

nome_aluno1 = input("Digite seu nome: ")
nota1_aluno1 = float(input("Digite sua primeira nota: "))
nota2_aluno1 = float(input("Digite sua segunda nota: "))

geral_aluno1 = Aluno(nome_aluno1, nota1_aluno1, nota2_aluno1)
media_aluno1 = geral_aluno1.media()

geral_aluno1.imprimir()
geral_aluno1.resultado()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Problema**

Isso acontece pois sua variável `self.media` tem o mesmo nome do método `media()`, e quando é executada a linha `media_aluno1 = geral_aluno1.media()`

**Solução simples**

Você pode renomear o método para algo como `gerar_media()` que este problema resolve